# how to export a file in GWT?

Tags: gwt

I am beginner in GWT. My web-application need to save information, that user was typed, to txt file - how to implement this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is: where do want to save the txt file? The GWT app is running in the browser, so you don't have access to the file system via the API (JavaScript is sandboxed), so your only option is to send the text to the server (using RPC or a HTTP POST) and save it there using your RemoteServiceServlet.

Answer (score 1):

If it is a small enough text file you could create a [Date URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) on the client which the client would then see as a downloadable file.

You can use this [utility](http://dataurl.net/#dataurlmaker) to try it out.